# how to debug phonegap android application on the phone itself

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm having some trouble getting debug mode to work on my android phone. I followed the instructions:

1. turn on debug mode in phone
2. set phone usb connection to pc mode
3. install google usb driver
4. connect android to pc, and then right click project->run as->android app

this results in my emulator popping up and nothing happening on my phone. What could I be missing here?

thanks

EDIT: got it working guys, I installed the OEM driver instead

Comment: I'm sorry, and what phone model? you may be better off grabbing a usb driver from the OEM. Let me know and I'll help further.

Comment: @TryTryAgain verizon droid 2, I installed my driver from http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html and it didn't give me any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have usb-debugging enabled on your phone.

Settings -> Applications -> Development.

[Here is link to a great source for this information.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: My bad, missed that. Did you make sure that your application has `Debuggable` set to true? It is the first step in that link i posted.

Comment: It tells you in that first step in the link i posted.

Comment: @prolink007 I think that's what he means by Step 1 ... on the phone it is checked... Step 1 is not talking about Eclipse, is how I interpreted it.

Comment: @TryTryAgain: His/her second step is what got me confused. But i think i understand what he/she meant.

Comment: ah ok. Yea I did everything they asked, and when I run adb devices, nothing comes up.

Comment: Try disconnecting the phone from your computer, restarting computer. Upon restart, launch eclipse and then plug your phone into your pc. Then check your `adb devices`. See what it says then.

Comment: @prolink007 that didn't work, but it looks like device manager is telling me that there is some issue with the driver.

Comment: You man need to download the drivers for your device (from their website and install those). I know i had to do that with my samsung galaxy s.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your title: *how to debug phonegap android application on the phone itself*

You can use a variety of apps that can capture the log for you. Which are absolutely helpful in debugging. And it gives you relatively (choose your filters or log mode; verbose, debug etc) the same information, although not same feel, as the **debugging PhoneGap** section below.

https://market.android.com/search?q=logcat

But for **debugging PhoneGap** see below...

Taken from http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting%20started%20with%20Android%20PhoneGap%20in%20Eclipse

> SOLUTION:
>        To get more information about what is going one while phonegap is running, run the Android log viewer. `adb logcat` if adb isn't found
>   you just need to do the full path to it something like
>   `~/projects/andriod/android-sdk-mac_86/tools/adb logcat`. If you have
>   both a device and a Android emulator running use -d and -e like so
>   `adb -e logcat`. This should give you more info about what is going
>   on. Here is a small example clipping form the android logs.

```
D/PhoneGapLog(  291): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js: Line 216 : TypeError: Result of expression 'accel' [undefined] is not an object.
E/Web Console(  291): TypeError: Result of expression 'accel' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js:216
D/dalvikvm(  117): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1727 objects / 91840 bytes in 110ms
D/PhoneGap(  291): The provider network is disabled
D/SntpClient(   61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

> From this we can see that the accel is not working. And some information about the location of the Error. This helps debug problems
>   and also helps you to give more information when asking the PhoneGap
>   community for help.

Comment: I'll edit my answer appropriately to include more device and driver information once we work through it @mugetsu